# Evaluated (maybe) $\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{Li}_2(t^x) \ln(1-t)} {t(1+x^2)}\ dt\ dx\ = -\frac{\pi^5}{144}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I might have proven that
$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{Li}_2(t^x) \ln(1-t)} {t(1+x^2)}\ dt\ dx\ = -\frac{\pi^5}{144}$$
If this turns out to be right I would be astonished by the fact that a monster dilogarithmic integral like that has such a nice closed form.

The problem is I am not able to check the if the result is correct, since the most powerful tool I have, WolframAlpha, can't compute the value of the integral. So if anybody can use some stronger math software like Maple or Mathematica to check if the result is correct I would be delighted. Thank you.

Comment: If you post your proof, we can check if it's valid. I suspect $a=-\ln t,\,b=-x\ln t$ is a useful change of variables; out of curiosity, did you use it?

Comment: Since $\operatorname{Li}_2(z)$ is the antiderivative of $\ln(1-z)/z$, some sort of integration by parts seems likely.

Comment: @J.G. No I didn't, I used integration by parts and then substituted $x=\frac{1}{y}$ in one of the resulting integrals

Comment: In fact, the integrand has the form $f(t^z)f'(t)/(1+x^2)$ just like the last one you posted. Did you try the change of variables I suggested there?

Comment: @eyeballfrog you got me, I found solution for the general case you mentioned. But I'm not skilled enough to replace two variables at a time as you suggested, so I tackled the problem by just looking at one integral at a time

Comment: By the way, two beautiful results that are derived in the same way are $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\1\frac{e^{t+t^x}}{1+x^2}\ dt\ dx= \frac{\pi}{4}(e^2-1)$ and $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\1\frac {\log(\Gamma(1+t^x))\psi(1+t)}{1+x^2}\ dt\ dx=0$

Comment: Part of the reason it works is that $\tan^{-1}(1/x)+\tan^{-1}(x)$ is a constant. Are there any other functions such that $g(x)  + g(1/x)$ is a constant? What about $g(x) + b g(1/x)$ for some constant $b$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be correct.
In WolframAlpha you have to write this:

Integrate[Integrate[Li(2,t^x)ln(1-t)/(t(1+x^2)),{t,0,1.0}],{x,0,infty}]

[Here the link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BIntegrate%5BLi%282%2Ct%5Ex%29ln%281-t%29%2F%28t%281%2Bx%5E2%29%29%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C1%7D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2Cinfty%7D%5D)

It doesn't give the closed form, but I tried to multiply the result for $\dfrac{144}{\pi^5}$ and the result is $-1$
For safety then I also multiplied it for $10^{20}$ (to see if there were any decimal digits other than $0$, but the result is always $10^{20}$, so at least the first 20 decimal digits are correct)

Comment: Mathematica Code: `NIntegrate[ PolyLog[2, t^x] Log[1 - t]/(t (1 + x^2)), {x, 0, Infinity}, {t, 0, 1}]` . Adjust the option `WorkingPrecision` or `PrecisionGoal` for optimal effect.

Answer (score 20):

I'll post a more general solution that includes this as a special case. Apply the changes of variables $t\rightarrow t^{1/x}$ followed by $x\rightarrow 1/x$ to get
$$
\int_0^\infty \int_0^1\frac{f(t^x)f'(t)}{1+x^2}dtdx = \int_0^\infty \int_0^1\frac{f(t)f'(t^{1/x})}{1+x^2}\frac{t^{1/x-1}}{x}dtdx = \int_0^\infty \int_0^1\frac{f(t)f'(t^x)}{1+x^2}xt^{x-1}dtdx.
$$
Integrate the last integral by parts in $t$ to get
$$
\int_0^\infty \int_0^1\frac{f(t^x)f'(t)}{1+x^2}dtdx =\int_0^\infty\frac{f(1)^2-f(0)^2}{1+x^2}dx-\int_0^\infty \int_0^1\frac{f'(t)f(t^x)}{1+x^2}dtdx.
$$
And thus,
$$
\int_0^\infty \int_0^1\frac{f(t^x)f'(t)}{1+x^2}dtdx =\frac{\pi}{4}\left[f(1)^2-f(0)^2\right].
$$
The given integral is the negative of the above for the case $f = \operatorname{Li}_2$. Which means
$$
\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{Li}_2(t^x) \ln(1-t)} {t(1+x^2)}\ dt\ dx\ = -\frac{\pi}{4}\left[\operatorname{Li}_2(1)^2-\operatorname{Li}_2(0)^2\right]=-\frac{\pi^5}{144}
$$

Comment: Yes I proved it in reverse, and with much more steps, your proof of the general case is extremely elegant.

Comment: A curious note is that the formula fails for $\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{\sin(t^x)\cos(t)}{1+x^2}\ dt\ dx$ that should be equal to $\frac{\pi}{4} \sin^2(1)$, but is not. Do you have come clue?

Comment: @Zima When I did the integral numerically it came out to $0.55612$, which is equal to $(\pi/4)\sin^2 1$.

Comment: You are right I mistyped it on wolfram

Comment: Very nice solution ! (+1)  for sure